# GET form action. Redirect to self

Tags: filters, actions, forms

I'm writing filter for posts by category on author page.

I send category name in $_GET array in this form:

```
<form action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" id="form1">
      <select name="type" class="form-select" id="edit-type">
           <option value="all">All</option>
           <option value="articles">Article</option>
           <option value="posts">Blog Post</option>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Apply" class="form-submit">
</form>
```

For exapmle I have link `www.mysite.com/?author=8`. If I type link `www.mysite.com/?author=8&type=posts`, all works correct, but if I use form, I'm redirect to home page just with parameter 'type' `www.mysite.com/?type=posts`

Also, I try to use in form action current page url, porblem is the same.

How can I send get parameter and redirect to slef page?

Comment: You are using the default permalinks?

Answer (score -1):

use `action="#"` or `action="<?php echo($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"`
to redirect to same page

Comment: Please explain *why* this answers OPs question.